# TV aerial loses signal over time

Tags: tv-antenna

I seem to have a strange issue with my TV aerial.
I installed a new all singing all dancing TV aerial and everything was fine for a month then the digital signal started going. I moved the aerial from my loft to the roof. This solved the problem for about a month and it started going again.

I have found out two things since. If I plug the aerial into my freeview talktalk box the signal goes after about a week and it takes about a month in my TV.
If I unplug the aerial for about 30 minutes and plug it back in the signal is good again but then goes again after a month or a week depending what it is plugged into.

I think this could be static build up but I dont know how I could solve this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If it's static buildup you can stop that with a [ground block](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B001I5610E/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_iJQpzb5R6RBFB) installed on the coax.  It sounds to me more like an amplified antenna where the amp is failing over time and disconnecting/reconnecting temporary gets it going again.

Comment: Is the antenna active or passive?

Comment: It could be corrosion buildup on connectors, which rubs off when removed and reconnected.Though there are commercial products to prevent corrosion, you might try cleaning the connectors with a toothbrush and applying a bit of automotive grease before reassembling, then covering with rubber tape or caulking.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I've not got an amplifier on the aerial. All the connections are new. However I'll take a closer look at them. The signal strength says 70% which I though should be enough